# bubble sort using assembly is stuck after input

Tags: assembly, bubble-sort, tasm

I am a complete novice in asm and i do not understand what mistake i am making, well, because i dont know where i could be wrong, so i need help, below is the code that i have tried to piece together using online resources

```
.MODEL SMALL
.386
.DATA

ARRAY DB 100 DUP (?)
N DB (?)
DATA DB (?)
ORDER EQU 0 ;implies ascending order

MSG1 DB 13,10,'Enter the number of elements in the array (0-9) : $'
MSG2 DB 13,10,'Enter the numbers : $'
MSG3 DB 13,10,'THE SORTED ARRAY IS:: $'

.CODE
.STARTUP

;print msg1
MOV DX,OFFSET MSG1
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

MOV EDX,0H
MOV EAX,0H
MOV SI,0

;take the number of elements
MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
SUB AL,30H
MOV N,AL
MOV AH,0
MOV CX,AX   ;CX now contains the size of array
MOV SI,0H

;enter the elements
INPUT:

MOV DX,OFFSET MSG2
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
SUB AL,30H
CMP AL,09H
JBE LABEL1
SUB AL,07H
LABEL1:
    MOV ARRAY[SI],AL
    INC SI
    LOOP INPUT

MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX
MOV BX,CX
DEC BX

NXTPASS:
    MOV CX,BX
    MOV SI,00H

NXTCOMP:
    MOV AL,ARRAY[SI]
    INC SI
    CMP AL,ARRAY[SI]
    IF ORDER EQ 0 ;ascending
    JB NEXT
    ELSE ;descending
    JA NEXT
    ENDIF
    XCHG AL,ARRAY[SI]
    MOV ARRAY[SI-1],AL

NEXT:
    LOOP NXTCOMP
    DEC BX
    JNZ NXTPASS
    MOV DX,OFFSET MSG3
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    MOV BX,CX
    MOV SI,00H

AGAIN: 
    MOV AL,ARRAY[SI]
    ADD AL,'0'
    MOV DL,AL
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H
    MOV AH,02H
    MOV DL,' '
    INT 21H
    INC SI
    DEC BX
    JNZ AGAIN

MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
END
```

If someone could tell me where i am making the error, i can try to fix it and get back to you

Comment: You haven't said what the error is. Regardless, you should use a debugger and step through the program one instruction at a time to find out where things go wrong.

Comment: The error was in the title, stuck after input, but thanks, i will try to use the debugger

Comment: There are multiple places you read input. Which one is stuck? Use a debugger to step through that part of the code.

Comment: Pay attention to the `MOV BX,CX`. What is in CX?

Comment: The numbers that are allowed on input range from 0 to F (one hexadecimal digit), yet the final output only considers numbers from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `MOV BX,CX` (from the comment by Raymond Chen), happens twice in your program.
The trouble is that you're using the value in `CX` right after a `LOOP` instruction has left it at zero.

- at the start of the bubble sort loop

  ```
    LOOP INPUT
    ...
    MOV BX,CX
  ```
- at the start of the display loop

  ```
    LOOP NXTCOMP
    ...
    MOV BX,CX
  ```

The solution is to actually use the variable *N* where you initially stored the number of array elements. For ease of use, you should define it word-sized like in below code:

```
N DW (?)
...
;take the number of elements
MOV AH, 01h
INT 21h
SUB AL, 30h
MOV AH, 0
MOV N, AX
```

And then those two `MOV BX,CX` instructions that were mentioned above, need to become `MOV BX, N`.

---

### Additional review

> ```
> 'Enter the number of elements in the array (0-9) : $'
> ```

- If you are going to allow a zero here then it would make sense to bypass inputting, bubbling, and displaying, and go directly to exit.
- There's some inconsistency between input and output. The numbers that are allowed on input can range from 0 to F (one hexadecimal digit), yet the final output only considers numbers from 0 to 9 (one decimal digit).
- So as to not exchange elements that are equal, you should change `JB` and `JA` into `JBE` and `JAE`:

  ```
    IF ORDER EQ 0   ; ascending
      JBE NEXT
    ELSE            ; descending
      JAE NEXT
    ENDIF
  ```
- It will be faster to not use the slow `XCHG` with a memory operand.

  ```
    mov  dl, ARRAY[SI]
    mov  ARRAY[si-1], dl
    mov  ARRAY[si], al
  ```